Is one's answer to this question really indicative of being neuro-atypical?
There are videos very similar to this going viral on tiktok over the last couple weeks, and they make a psychological claim I'm skeptical of.
The premise is this: You ask someone, "What do 2 and 7 have in common?", and a neuro-typical, supposedly, will usually answer with "they're both numbers", but non neuro-typicals (people with some type of autism or ADHD, usually is the implication) will answer with something like how they look similar, or how they have the same vibe, or something like that.
Is there any real evidence that the answer to this question is meaningful in that way?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

It's problematic because: Tests for austistic spectrum disorders are usually performed by teams of people, with highly specialist training, using a set variety of sophisticated tests and observational techniques over a period of often many months. A single question that's not part of any standardized test can't be seen as having any statistical significance. That being said, you might get lucky and chance upon such a pattern as the videos suggest - but they would not preclude alternative possible explanations (either everyday ones or other psychiatric conditions).
